# Can I deliver protected video content from the Amazon S3 service

Tags: video, e-commerce, amazon-s3

Revision on initial post:

I'm looking to deliver video content after a purchase of content is complete. Here are my requirements

1. I need to protect content until purchase exists
2. I want to use the Amazon S3 service because it is cost effective

So that is about it, as I said before I would most likely use PHP to call the file from the S3 service and stream it on the page, as long as the purchase can be confirmed.

Is this feasible, do you see any hurdles or issues?

Comment: I think you're going to need to make your question a little more explicit.  What's your requirement for "secure"?  DRM can always be broken, etc.  Also, what does "calling the videos into a browser window" mean?  That's not a term I'm familiar with.  I'm tempted to vote to close as not a real question, but I'll give you a chance to flesh it out :)

Comment: By 'deliver' do you mean stream ONCE and ONLY ONCE or do you mean you want allow the purchaser to get the actual video file?

Comment: Stream - possibly set an expiration on the stream